# Add ajax preloaded content to link

Tags: jquery, ajax, hyperlink, preloader

I have made a function (slightly messy) that lets me dynamically add my php content files into my site's main content div. It's working fine, but it takes quite a long time to load on mobile devices.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(pageLoader());

function pageLoader() {
    $.get("content/home.php", function(data){
        $("#mainContent").html(data);
    });
    $("#destinationLink").on("click", function() {  
        $.get("content/destinations.php", function(data){
            $("#mainContent").html(data);
        });
        var position = $("html, body");
        position.animate({scrollTop: $( $(this).attr("href")).offset().top - 50}, 1500, "easeInOutQuint");
        return false;
    });
    $("#homeLink").on("click", function() {
        $.get("content/home.php", function(data){
            $("#mainContent").html(data);
        });
        var position = $("html, body");
        position.animate({
            scrollTop: $( $(this).attr("href")).offset().top
        }, 1500, "easeInOutQuint");
        return false;
    });
    $("#contactsLink").on("click", function() {
        $.get("content/contacts.php", function(data){
            $("#mainContent").html(data);
        });
    });
}
```

I want to get all the files to preload so that transitions between pages is a little smoother. I tried to add the get ajax calls to the on load javascript function but it just loads them all into the div together.

Any help to simplify the code and add the preloading function would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Get rid of the parentheses, it should be `$(document).ready(pageLoader);`.

Comment: I don't understand the quesiton. This is mostly just setting up click handlers that load different pages into the `mainContent` DIV. It's not preloading anything else.

Comment: What you could do is use AJAX to load all the other pages into hidden DIVs in the background. Then the click handlers would just show those DIVs.

Comment: That works, thank you! Although I wonder how this will impact initial load times on mobile devices.

Comment: Since AJAX runs asynchronously, I don't think it should impact the initial load time.